# Components Not Re-Rendering when Action is Dispatched and State Updates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, web-component

When I click on one of my InspectorOption components, my redux logger shows that an action is dispatched and the state updates as expected.

My InspectorSelect and children InspectorOption components use react-redux's connect to mapStateToProps and these component depend on those props that come from state.

But even though the state is updating and the components depend on state, the components are not re-rendering when the state updates.

Why are my components not re-rendering when the state changes and how do I correct this?

```
@connect((state) => {
    return {
        options: state.inspector.options
    }
})
export default class InspectorSelect extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {
                    this.props.options.map(option => {
                        return <InspectorOption 
                            option={ option }
                            key={ option.id }
                        />
                    })
                }
            </div>
        )
    }   
}
```

https://github.com/caseysiebel/dashboard/blob/master/src/components/InspectorSelect.js#L17

Comment: 99.9% of the time, it's due to accidental mutation of Redux state in a reducer (or elsewhere in your code).  See http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/ReactRedux.html#react-not-rerendering .

Comment: As previous comment states, it is probably caused by mutation of state. If you would post your reducers someone mighr be able to spot the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @markerikson noted: *99.9% of the time, it's due to accidental mutation of Redux state in a reducer*

There is a mutation in `dashboard/src/reducers/inspector.js`

```
export default function reducer(state = {
    options: [] 
}, action) {

    switch (action.type){
        case 'SET_INSPECTOR': 
            state.options = state.options.map(option => {   // <-- mutation here
                return option.id === action.payload ?
                    { ...option, active: true } :
                    { ...option, active: false }
            })
            return state // returning mutated state
        default: 
            return state
    }
}
```

should be

```
export default function reducer(state = {
    options: [] 
}, action) {

    switch (action.type){
        case 'SET_INSPECTOR': 
            var newOptions = state.options.map(option => {
                return option.id === action.payload ?
                    { ...option, active: true } :
                    { ...option, active: false }
            });
            return {...state, options: newOptions}  // returning new state
        default: 
            return state
    }
}
```

Comment: Good eye! :)  Yep, that'd be a mutation of `state`.